# MongoDB relations strategy, using mongoose node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, relation

right now I am using MongoDB for the first time, and I have the need to implement relations. As far as I understand the standard way to go is to use this:

```
stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
```

But if I want to have a many to many relation I have to perform the push action on 2 objects right? So my idea was to define a Relation model which joins 2 objects by holding a ref to each object. But how can I define the 'ref' parts of the above code dynamically. Is there a more elegant way ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: MongoDB is not a relational database so relations might not be your best option. Take a good hard look at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/#data-models and perhaps reconsider if MongoDB is the right tool for the job.

Comment: If you have relations it is best to use tool meant to be used for such problems - relational database. For that you can use Waterline ORM or many other great libraries in combination with Mysql, PostgreSQL or others

Comment: Ok it seems like I have to choose a different db then. I just made a quick search and stubmeld upon couchDB(very intersting because of sync with pouchDB), is this a better solution ? Any articles you might recommend?